# Migrate Homework to Math.SE instead of close?

Tags: discussion

Why not migrate the low-level "check my answer" type questions to math.se where they are receptive to them?

The "Economics" Stackexchange never made it out of Beta: there were so many beginner's level questions that no experts could stand the place. 
The "[quantitative finance](https://quant.stackexchange.com/)" site however has such an intimidating name that it successfully scares off the homework "check my answer" type people that regularly encounter the "closed as off topic" homework tag here on Physics.SE

Perhaps we appear too approachable. Maybe something more intimidating like "Quantitative Science" might scare off unwanted questions. Till then, why not migrate the "check my answer" questions to math.se where they are receptive to them?

Also, I believe that the Mechanical Engineering SE Beta failed for the same reason as Economics.SE

Comment: You do have to close as "off topic" in order to migrate, you know. Also, the Don't Migrate Crap policy is relevant.

Comment: @Dale: For completeness, please link to the other SE sites you mention.

Answer (score 6):

The answer is really very simple: This is a bad idea, because *not all physics homework exercises are on-topic on a different site* (in fact, I suspect most aren't). If a question is about physics, it makes zero sense to migrate it to Math.SE. As for homework-type questions that are purely mathematical in nature, I believe we're *already* migrating those to Math.SE.

Comment: [This](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/195863/solving-for-the-resonant-frequencies-of-a-mass-spring-system?noredirect=1#comment418101_195863) purely mathmatical question of mine was closed - not migrated, and John's answer was maliciously deleted.

Comment: @Dale *maliciously deleted*? Do you think there was an evil plan, or perhaps a conspiracy against you, behind it?

Comment: I often tend to close homework-like questions without too much thought about whether they would be suitable for migration, because I've heard from the Math mods that while they don't have the kinds of aggressive homework restrictions we do, they don't really _like_ such questions either. And it's not so hard to repost the question if someone really wants to try it out on [math.SE].

Comment: @Dale: answers to homework questions are always deleted as part of our policy of discouraging homework questions. In this case I imagine the answer was deleted before the question was migrated. If you ask the mods on the Math SE site I expect they will be happy to undelete John's answer.

Comment: Technically speaking,  [Dale's question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/195863/2451) was not migrated but [re-asked](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1374469/11127). User john has already copied his answer there.